# C++/CLI static lib project using NET 4.5 is referencing NET 4.0 System.dll

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, c++-cli, .net-4.5

I created a C++/CLI project within a larger solution as a static library.

I added **$(FrameworkPathOverride)** in Properties/C/C++: "Additional #using Directories".

I manually added `<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>` to the project file, and I also set the '***Visual Studio 2013 (v120)***' for Platform Toolset.

So the project looks OK now and is showing NET 4.5 in the References tab.

Then I went to the References tab to add **System.dll**. The list shows me only 4.0 framework assemblies, and when I choose System it adds the System.dll file to the project. 
However, the added System.dll file comes from local ***GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__xxx*** folder that has NET 4.0 assemblies and  there is nothing I can do to change it.

I expected to see the '***C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5***' path there, rather than 4.0 GAC.

This actually creates a problem, because as I now add a reference to another project in the solution (this time a C# class library) that is referencing System.dll from the 4.5 Framework location, then there is a System.dll collision, which results in the following error:

```
warning C4945: 'Regex' : cannot import symbol from 'c:\program files (x86)\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.5\system.dll': as 'System::Text::RegularExpressions::Regex' has already been imported from another assembly 'System'
2>          c:\windows\microsoft.net\assembly\gac_msil\system\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\system.dll : see declaration of 'System::Text::RegularExpressions::Regex'
```

Is there any way to make a NET 4.5 C++/CLI static library project reference System.dll from the 4.5 Framework location?

Thanks

Comment: I've read elsewhere on SO, that 4.5 is a drop in replacement for 4.0. And the 4.5 assemblies will reside in the directory you mentioned. Directories with the various versions of the 4.x assemblies are somewhere in the \program files dir structure. If you find the other post on SO it will have which directory that is. I also read the only real way to know the difference at runtime is to use a feature in 4.5 that doesn't exist in 4.0

Comment: Very hard to guess what you are doing to get the path so messed up.  The version is fine.  Starting point is already wrong, you cannot create a static library project.  That produces a .lib file and is only usable when it is linked.  The linker does not support that.  You *must* use the Visual C++ > CLR > Class Library project template.

Comment: @HansPassant I've just spent *days* trying to work out why I can't use .Net 4.5 with a new "Empty Project" that I've turned up clr support for.  I#ve now found i get .Net 4.5.2 it I use the Visual C++ > CLR > "Empty CLR Project" template.  Thanks, you've saved what remains of my hair!!